# Azure function deployment: What is local.settings.json?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have created a github repository like the official [one](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/functions-quickstart) with all my Azure functions. A function is triggered by a Service Bus and so I have put in function.json the connection string of this service. However, I got an error :

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: 
Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string <..> 
is missing or empty
```

I searched on internet that I have to create a local.setting.json and put inside the value of the connection string. However, i did not understand where I should add this file and specially how if I want to autoimatically deploy my functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string 'AzureWebJobsAzureSBConnection' is missing or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988838/azure-webjobs-sdk-servicebus-connection-string-azurewebjobsazuresbconnection-i)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Local.settings.json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-run-local) is for testing you Azure Function locally on your machine.  When deployed to Azure, you set the [Application Settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup#set-the-connection-string) under the function app.

Comment: Is that possible to do it with Azure cli or Azure Resources manager ? Through webgui is not good for production.

Comment: Here is an example arm template.  Take note of. appSettings. https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/blob/master/201-function-app-dedicated-github-deploy/azuredeploy.json