# How to resolve provider is null error while invoking azure service bus from azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I took care of all the settings described here [Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string 'AzureWebJobsAzureSBConnection' is missing or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42988838/azure-webjobs-sdk-servicebus-connection-string-azurewebjobsazuresbconnection-i/42991693#42991693)

Here is my local.settings.json looks like

```
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  },
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "AzureWebJobsAzureSBConnection": "Endpoint=sb://host.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xx"
  }

}
```

Still I get this error.

Here is the function looks like

```
public static class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("ServiceBusQueueTriggerCSharp")]
        public static void Run(
     [ServiceBusTrigger("queue", Connection = "Endpoint=sb://host.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xxxx")]

     ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# ServiceBus queue trigger function processed message:");

        }
    }
```

A host error has occurred during startup operation '952d758d-8e6c-4159-bc78-ee315de1b93a'.
[2021-08-25T12:41:13.453Z] Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus: Microsoft Azure WebJobs SDK ServiceBus connection string 'Endpoint=sb://host.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;[Hidden Credential]' is missing or empty.
Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'provider')

Comment: Thats probably because you've used the wrong `Connection` value in the `[ServiceBusTrigger]` attribute (see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-service-bus-trigger?tabs=csharp#attributes-and-annotations)). You have 2 options. Option 1: 
`[ServiceBusTrigger("queue")]` => remove the Connection and update appsettings: `AzureWebJobsServiceBus: xx`
Option 2: 
`[ServiceBusTrigger("queue", Connection = "ConnectionStrings:AzureWebJobsAzureSBConnection")]`

Comment: @Melissa, For option1 There is no appsettings.json file , instead there is local.settings.json , do i need to add one and how does it takes the config from appsettings?

Comment: Sorry, you can update it in `local.settings.json`. But place the `AzureWebJobsServiceBus`  inside the `Values` element.

Comment: Something like this: ```{
 "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsServiceBus": "Endpoint=sb://host.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xx",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you [Melissa](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3652378/melissa). Posting your suggestion as an answer to help community members.

You can update `local.settings.json` and place `AzureWebJobsServiceBus` inside the `Values` element.

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "AzureWebJobsServiceBus": "Endpoint=sb://host.servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=RootManageSharedAccessKey;SharedAccessKey=xx",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet"
  }
}
```